# Make a vertical responsive grid

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I’m using bootstrap which as you know is based on a 12 grids horizontally, but what if you want fit these boxes in height alongside of width ([fit the boxes in length automatically, for instance with some percentage for each div length, like width](http://up.liz.ir/files/Snap%202013-11-10%20at%2022_56_26.png)).

I’ve tried some Jquery based script like Manson, but it is not responsive (something like [this](http://www.basicoh.com/demo/transition/)).

Comment: I think you need to specfify a little bit better, what youre trying to achive. What do you mean by repsonsive and how should the grid behave exactly?

Comment: sorry if it was not clear. I just edited my first link to became more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cant to achieve your exact example then it's quite simple:
You just make 4 boxes which all have position absolute, you give them width and height 50%.

Next up is to position the element in each corner. To do that, you give each box a unique id.
They could be #topLeft, #topRight, #bottomLeft, #bottomRight.
And then you just add css to those classes like this:

```
#topLeft {
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
#topRight {
top: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

Comment: percentage values are your friend.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest, that you check out different horizontal oriented grids and how they use min-width and different row and comlumn-classes.You should be able to use `min-height` and `max-height` instead of min-width and max-width and height instead of width.

It depends on what you want to achieve, what the best approach for such a grid would be.